# Access [routerLinkActive] value in component class

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a tab component TabComponent which has the following HTML template:

```html
<a [routerLink]='link' [routerLinkActive]="[is-active]">link label</a>
<button>Close tab</button>
```

I would like to access the value of the [routerLinkActive] property, basically I would like to get a variable inside the component class that indicates if this routerLink is active. How can I access it from within the component class?

**EDIT**: I think if I can get access to the CSS class of the `<a>` link tag the work is done, is there a way to access it?

Comment: `routerLinkActive` doesn't have a public property to access the state. You can copy the code and adjust it to your needs to get the active state https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/dabf214f170eda8e1ecd2ff4ab252738e7aa0ddb/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts

Comment: Reading the CSS class is quite ugly. In Angular2 the DOM should reflect the model (using binding) but the controller should avoid accessing the DOM directly.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this will help at all but, you can get the values in your template like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let child of directory; let i = index;"
   routerLink="{{child.route}}"
   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">

   <h3>{{rla.isActive}}</h3><!--Displays boolean indicating whether or not you are navigated to this link-->
</a>
```

Now, a boolean will display in your h3 indicating whether or not you are currently navigated to the link.

While this works as a template variable, I have been unable to pass the value to the component.ts or pass it to other template directives e.g

```
 <a *ngFor="let child of directory; let i = index;"
   routerLink="{{child.route}}"
   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"

   [active]="rla.isActive" <!--This doesn't insert the boolean here for some reason-->
   >    
   <h3>{{rla.isActive}}</h3>
</a>
```

I hope this helps. Please update if you get any closer to a good solution.

Comment: The `#rla="routerLinkActive"` solution still works in 2020 with NG9. Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the state of isActive in the component, you need to wait for the AfterContentChecked lifecycle callback.

```html
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
  Bob {{ rla.isActive ? '(already open)' : ''}}
</a>
```

```js
@ViewChild('rla') private rla: RouterLinkActive;

ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    if (this.rla?.isActive) {
        console.log('isActive')
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer.

Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

you can get access to routerLinkActive with `@ViewChild()` decorator

`@ViewChild(RouterLinkActive) private routerLinkActive: RouterLinkActive;`

but the problem here is that its values are not set immmediately, so for most cases during component render `isActive` will be false, and only later Router will set it to true.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension of Nayfin's answer, this also works (tested in Angular 11).

This is using the template variable to set a property, not as part of an ngFor. You have to use a different template variable for each component.

```
<a routerLink="/route1" routerLinkActive #route1RLA="routerLinkActive" [active]="route1RLA.isActive">Route 1</a>
<a routerLink="/route2" routerLinkActive #route2RLA="routerLinkActive" [active]="route2RLA.isActive">Route 2</a>
<a routerLink="/route3" routerLinkActive #route3RLA="routerLinkActive" [active]="route3RLA.isActive">Route 3</a>
```